# SQL Pull Revenue Periods Where Start Date Stays Constant but End Date Changes

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I used the code below to get the the metrics to date for our 4 loyalty tiers. I want to get those numbers from the beginning of time through end end of each month as period in order to see the growth of the loyalty program. Do you know how to make the periods where the start does stays the beginning of time instead of the begging of the month??

```
SELECT
    inside.loyalty_tier,
    SUM(inside.customers) AS "customers",
    SUM(inside.orders) AS "orders",
    SUM(inside.net_sales) AS "net_sales",
    SUM(inside.time_between_sales) AS "time_between_sales"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            customer_email,
            CASE WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 0 AND 124.99 THEN 'no_tier' 
                WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 125 AND 198.99 THEN 'almost_vip' 
                WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) BETWEEN 199 AND 749.99 THEN 'vip' 
                WHEN SUM(SCM.net_sales) >= 750 THEN 'the_players_club' 
                ELSE NULL 
            END AS "loyalty_tier",
            COUNT(DISTINCT SCM.customer_email) AS "customers",
            COUNT(DISTINCT SCM.order_id) AS "orders",
            SUM(SCM.net_sales) AS "net_sales",
            DATEDIFF(day, MIN(SCM.timestamp), MAX(SCM.timestamp)) AS "time_between_sales"
        FROM  {{ @public_fact_shopify_criquet_master AS SCM }}
        WHERE SCM.net_sales > 0
        GROUP BY customer_email
    ) AS inside
GROUP BY inside.loyalty_tier
```

Sample Output Image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEpXV.png

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Comment: this currently shows the tier name, number of customers in that tier, number of orders from those customers, total net sales from those orders and total time between first and last orders from those customers. That is from the date range 2011-11-1 - Now. I want to add a column that would be the first column that would be Year-Month so that if the first column was 2011-12 it would get data from 2011-11-1 - 2011-12-31 or if it was 2013-1 it would be 2011-11-1 - 2013-1-31.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output , the solution  depends on how your data look

Comment: A sample output is now attached at the bottom of the question